# After upgrade to 22.04.1 media playback is slow

Tags: media, playback

I upgraded to 22.04.1 earlier this week.

I noticed that web based media playback (Youtube, Tidal.com, etc) sounded slow.
I compared it to media play back on my phone (Android) and confirmed that the media is playing more slowly.

I see other people discussing this. Some have mentioned installing an update. But I just did a major upgrade 2 days ago.

Are there any changes that I need to make to get media to play back normally?

Comment: More info.
VLC has this problem too. The playback is spotty and broken up a bit.
So the stream source is not critical.
Sorry for the red herring.

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of posting comments.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Which graphics card? Are you sure your system is fully updated?

Comment: Hello,

Version/Video card info:

tomas@tomas-Modern-14-B11SB:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy

tomas@tomas-Modern-14-B11SB:~$ lspci |grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 01)

Version:
Updater ran yesterday. No updates available today.
This problem happens with all browser and also with VLC.